# request for a specific client certificate in nettcp bindings

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config

Is it possible to configure net tcp binding
to request a specific certificate to be supplied by the client ?
not just certificate which is trusted by the server but the exact same certificate defined in the server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use netTcpBinding and need a specific certificate to verify, you can view my demo.
This is the app.config in service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.Samples.X509CertificateValidator.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <!-- use host/baseAddresses to configure base address provided by host -->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8040/servicemodelsamples/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- use base address specified above, provide one endpoint -->
        <endpoint address="certificate" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding" contract="Microsoft.Samples.X509CertificateValidator.ICalculator"/>
      </service>
    </services>
 
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <!-- X509 certificate binding -->
        <binding name="Binding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

In the behavior node, we can specify the information of the certificate to be used.

```
 <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
           
            <clientCertificate>
             
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="Microsoft.Samples.X509CertificateValidator.CustomX509CertificateValidator, service"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    
  </system.serviceModel>
 
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

This is the app.config in client:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
 
    <client>
      <!-- X509 certificate based endpoint -->
      <endpoint name="Certificate" address="net.tcp://localhost:8040/servicemodelsamples/service/certificate" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding" behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior" contract="Microsoft.Samples.X509CertificateValidator.ICalculator">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
 
    <bindings>
          <netTcpBinding>
        <!-- X509 certificate binding -->
        <binding name="Binding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
          </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
             <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
 
  </system.serviceModel>
 
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

In client.cs, we need to specify the certificate to be used through the setcertificate method.

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "alice");
```

Comment: Thank, but in your example the server will accept any certificate which can be validated not a specific one.

Comment: You can override the validate methods in the X509CertificateValidator in the service to filter the certificates. (regarding the class:X509CertificateValidator, you can view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)